# Gif pictures on windows desktop

Tags: windows, desktop, gif, animated-gif

I have some animated gif that I want to put on my desktop.

Do you know some sort of software to do this? I would like them to be in the form of movable panels (such as done in the "fences", but the fences for the icons, they can not put a background image, the more animated)

Comment: I've stumbled into the 1990's ;-)

Comment: absolutely, gif's may have really good quality, [like this](http://i.imgur.com/efJvP.gif)

Comment: Doesn't Windows have this built in, under the name of "Active Desktop"? (Speaking of, **which operating system**, @Fedcomp?)

Comment: Ha, awesome, nice little bit of work that. I remember they were all the rage when I first started getting into PC's in a big way. My friend had them everywhere. it was kind of his calling card.

Comment: **Active Desktop** removed after win98

Comment: So which OS do you have then, please?

Comment: @Fedcomp: Uh, removed? It still exists in Windows XP. Makes for [great wallpapers](http://twistori.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [Windows Dreamscene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Dreamscene) is the way to go:

> Windows DreamScene is a utility that allows videos and other optimized animations to be used as desktop wallpapers. It is one of the Windows Ultimate Extras.